# SSH session hanging the remote desktop

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I have been remotely connecting to my ubuntu dekstop at work using SSH, I have noticed that after some ideal time the connection hangs and on restarting the SSH, ssh does not identify my desktop on the remote side. Later I observed that the remote desktop usually hangs up when my ssh connection hangs up? Could anyone help with this?
I usually forward ports in SSH as there is an intermediate server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prevent ssh hanging up on  your, you can set up some things in your ssh setup.

edit/or create this file

```
pico ~/.ssh/config
```

add these lines

```
Host Remotehost
 Hostname myremotehost.com
 ServerAliveInterval 240
```

alternative you can make this rule for ALL your ssh connections like this

```
Host *
 ServerAliveInterval 240
```

if you are on windows, putty also have keep alive settings.

oh, and do not forget to set the correct permission for this config file like this:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/98562/way-to-avoid-ssh-connection-timeout-freezing-of-terminal-tab)